# You are the Host of the Olympics!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

You host the Olympic Games, and need to build a fantastic pool for the sake of the occasion, but the supervisors often change their mind regarding the dimensions, and need a quick way to rebuild it with the requested size!

---

Given two integers, `L` and `x`, your task is to build a swimming pool of length `L` and `x` lanes.

## How is a pool built?

- It contains an inner square, whose horizontal walls are made of `L` consecutive dashes(`-`) , and whose vertical walls are made out of `3x - 1` bars (`|`). Additionally, 4 `+` signs lie in each corner. Let's have an example (`L = 10, x = 2`):

  ```
  +----------+
  |          |
  |          |
  |          |
  |          |
  |          |
  +----------+
  ```
- *Each lane* has a width of 2 vertical units. The inner square is filled with `x-1` lane separators, consisting of `L` horizontally consecutive `:` symbols. After putting the lane separators, our pool should look like this:

  ```
  +----------+
  |          |
  |          |
  |::::::::::|
  |          |
  |          |
  +----------+
  ```
- A pool also contains a *padding* (an outer square), whose horizontal walls are (L+4) `-`s and whose vertical walls are (3x + 1) `|`s, that surrounds the inner square:

  ```
  +--------------+
  | +----------+ |
  | |          | |
  | |          | |
  | |::::::::::| |
  | |          | |
  | |          | |
  | +----------+ |
  +--------------+
  ```

And that's our olympic-sized** swimming pool!

---

## Specs:

- For design and functionality purposes, you are guaranteed that `100 ≥ L ≥ 10` and `15 ≥ x ≥ 2`.
- The output must be exactly as shown. Outputting a "vertically-built"* pool is disallowed.
- Trailing and leading spaces are allowed.
- You may take input and provide output through [any standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

---

## Examples / Test cases:

```
L = 20, x = 3

+------------------------+
| +--------------------+ |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| |::::::::::::::::::::| |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| |::::::::::::::::::::| |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
| +--------------------+ |
+------------------------+



L = 50, x = 5:

+------------------------------------------------------+
| +--------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::| |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::| |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::| |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::| |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| +--------------------------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------------------------+


L = 10, x =15

+--------------+
| +----------+ |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| |::::::::::| |
| |          | |
| |          | |
| +----------+ |
+--------------+
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code *in bytes* wins!

<sub>*The water could flow out if it is built vertically :P</sub>

<sub>**Yes, I am aware that the more the lanes are and the shorter the pool is, the less the drawing looks like a pool!</sub>

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/12992#12992), for those who can view deleted posts.

Comment: What should happen if `x>=L`??

Comment: @CraigR8806 The same algorithm. Just with more lanes than the length of the pool. I have a feeling that you have mistread the question...

Comment: What about the case where `L=10` and `x=15`? Would there not be more lanes than could be placed in the pool?  I could be misunderstanding the intent

Comment: @CraigR8806 The length has nothing to do with the lanes! You can test it yourself with one of the existing answers

Comment: @CraigR8806 Added a test case on that

Comment: Sorry, I now see where I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60790/discussion-between-mr-xcoder-and-craigr8806).

Comment: I hate these kind of problems.

Comment: Why is that @pagie_ ??

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder  I've tried to do them in Python. They frustrate me, especially when the user has to input the size of the shape.

Comment: You forgot to say if a full program was required or a function will do.

Comment: @DavidConrad "You can take input and provide output by [any standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)". That includes both functions and programs.

Answer (score 13):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
ＮθＮη↓Ｅθ×η:  Ｂ⁺θ²⁺×³η¹↖←Ｂ⁺θ⁶⁺×³η³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nnXndoCI7Y/aJr/fs/TcjsPTz223UlB4v2fRo8Zd53Yc2gSkDk8/tPnc9kM7H7VNe9Q2ASb1qHEbQm7z//@mBlymAA)

-4 thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

AST:

```
Program
├Ｎ: Input Number
│└θ: Identifier θ
├Ｎ: Input Number
│└η: Identifier η
├Print
│├↓: Down
│└Ｅ: Map
│ ├θ: Identifier θ
│ └×: Product
│  ├η: Identifier η
│  └':  ': String ':  '
├Ｂ: Box
│├⁺: Sum
││├θ: Identifier θ
││└2: Number 2
│└⁺: Sum
│ ├×: Product
│ │├3: Number 3
│ │└η: Identifier η
│ └1: Number 1
├Move
│└↖: Up Left
├Move
│└←: Left
└Ｂ: Box
 ├⁺: Sum
 │├θ: Identifier θ
 │└6: Number 6
 └⁺: Sum
  ├×: Product
  │├3: Number 3
  │└η: Identifier η
  └3: Number 3
```

Comment: wow Charcoal has got this challenge down :)

Comment: You stayed true to your name - you have me outgolfed.

Comment: As usual, explanation request.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Yeah, I don't have time to do all those explanations while I'm seeking something to outgolf...also you can check the AST using the `-a` command-line argument.

Comment: why does `-a` raise error >_<

Comment: 32 bytes: `ＮθＮη↓Ｅθ×η:  Ｂ⁺θ²⁺×³η¹↖←Ｂ⁺θ⁶⁺×³η³`.

Comment: @Neil Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer SO comments collapse consecutive spaces, as you would have noticed if you'd checked the apparent byte count of the string ;-)

Answer (score 12):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>40</strike> <strike>39</strike> 37 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＢ⁺θ⁶⁺×³η³↘→Ｂ⁺θ²⁺×³η¹→Ｆ⁻η¹«Ｍ³↓Ｐ×:θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nnXndoCI7e/3LHrUuOvcjkeN24D04emHNp/bfmjzo7YZj9omweQObUJI7QSLL3vUuBvEObT6/Z61IOWT3@/ZcHi61bkd//9HmxroKJjGAgA)

I know [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) already has a Charcoal answer of around the same length, but I took a bit of a different approach so I figured I may as well also post mine.

### Explanation

```
ＮθＮηＢ⁺θ⁶⁺×³η³↘→Ｂ⁺θ²⁺×³η¹→Ｆ⁻η¹«Ｍ³↓Ｐ×:θ
ＮθＮη                                         take the two inputs as numbers in θ and η
      Ｂ⁺θ⁶⁺×³η³                               draw a rectangle θ + 6 by 3η + 3
                                               (characters default to |, - and +)
                ↘→                             move the cursor down one and right two
                   Ｂ⁺θ²⁺×³η¹                  draw a rectangle θ + 2 by 3η + 1
                             Ｆ⁻η¹«            for ι (unused) from 0 up until η - 1:
                                   Ｍ³↓            move the cursor down by 3
                                       Ｐ×:θ       print θ :s without moving the cursor
                                               [implicit end of for]
```

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Added.

Comment: Huh, so the third parameter to `Ｂ` is optional? Nice, that saves me two bytes!

Answer (score 11):

## Charcoal, <s>40</s> <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 31 bytes

```
Ａ⁺²ＮθＡ⁺¹×³ＮηＵＯθη:¶¶Ｂθη↖←Ｂ⁺⁴θ⁺²η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8jIKe0WMNIR8Ezr6C0xK80Nym1SENTU0ehUNOaC1mJoY5CSGZuarGGMbpaoOIMoGL/pJz8vHSNQiBPR0HJKiYvJk8JKOyUXwEWAzJ988tSNaxCC3xS00rgXCgHpAxsjwnIah0FmLMyNDWt//83NeAy/a9b9l@3OAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ａ⁺²Ｎθ       Assign(Plus(2, InputNumber()), q);
```

Charcoal's drawing primitives use the overall character count including `+`s, however the input is just the number of `-`s, so we need to add 2 to obtain the width of the inner wall.

```
Ａ⁺¹×³Ｎη     Assign(Plus(1, Times(3, InputNumber())), h);
```

Calculate the height of the inner wall, again, inclusive of the bottom row, so three per lane plus one.

```
ＵＯθη:¶¶     Oblong(q, h, ":\n\n");
```

Draw the lanes. This is simply a rectangle filled with `:`s vertically separated by two blank lines (the pilcrows represent newline characters).

```
Ｂθη         Box(q, h);
```

The `Rectangle` command is exactly what we need to draw the inner wall. Edit: `Box` allows you to omit its third parameter, saving me 2 bytes.

```
↖           Move(:UpLeft);
←           Move(:Left);
Ｂ⁺⁴θ⁺²η     Box(Plus(4, q), Plus(2, h));
```

And again to draw the outer wall, except slightly wider and taller, and centred on the inner wall.

Comment: Why are the links to Charcoal code at TIO never to the actual code?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I link to the verbose code because it's more readable, plus I add the argument to generate the succinct code automatically for verification purposes.

Comment: ...but how is 219 characters more readable than 40? :p

Comment: I could have just looked harder and noticed [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120510/53748) :)

Comment: As usual, please explain.

Comment: Somewhat. A full codeblock of explanation would be optimal, however.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Bah, just as soon as I write an explanation I find a 1-byte golf, and now I'm going to need a new explanation...

Comment: RIP explanation. Also, can you include concise code in the explanation?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline New golf, new explanation!

Comment: Congrats on tying me :)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer If only the 3-argument version of `Box` didn't move the cursor I'd be down to 35 bytes, sigh...

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>137</s> 124 bytes

Golfed it down a bit on my phone, more to follow.

```js
x=>y=>`+--0--+
| +0+ |
${((a=`| |1| |
`)+a+`| |2| |
`).repeat(y-1)+a+a}| +0+ |
+--0--+`.replace(/\d/g,n=>"- :"[n].repeat(x))
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
x=>y=>`+--0--+
| +0+ |
${((a=`| |1| |
`)+a+`| |2| |
`).repeat(y-1)+a+a}| +0+ |
+--0--+`.replace(/\d/g,n=>"- :"[n].repeat(x))
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)(+j.value);o.innerText=f(i.value=50)(j.value=5)
```

```css
input{font-family:sans-serif;margin:0 5px 0 0;width:50px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>L: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>x: </label><input id=j type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: I like this one because it's interactive :D

Comment: @xDaizu, check out some of my other JS solutions, so ;)

Answer (score 8):

## T-SQL, <s>284</s> 281 bytes

```
DECLARE @ INT,@x INT,@S VARCHAR(MAX)='+--d--+b| +d+ |b'SELECT @=L,@x=x FROM t
P:SET @S+='| |s| |b| |s| |b| |c| |b'SET @x-=1IF @x>0GOTO P
PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(@S,LEN(@S)-6)+'+d+ |b+--d--+','d',REPLICATE('-',@)),'b',CHAR(13)),'s',SPACE(@)),'c',REPLICATE(':',@))
```

Input is taken from INT columns **L** and **x** in preexisting table **t**, [per our allowed input methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Basically I'm creating a long string with letters representing the repeated characters (d=dashes, s=spaces, c=colons, b=line break), then REPLACE them all at the end with the appropriate fillers.

Formatted:

```
DECLARE @ INT,@x INT,@S VARCHAR(MAX)='+--d--+b| +d+ |b'
SELECT @=L,@x=x FROM t
P:
    SET @S+='| |s| |b| |s| |b| |c| |b'
    SET @x-=1
IF @x>0 GOTO P
PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( LEFT(@S,LEN(@S)-6)+'+d+ |b+--d--+'
     ,'d',REPLICATE('-',@))
     ,'b',CHAR(13))
     ,'s',SPACE(@))
     ,'c',REPLICATE(':',@))
```

Inside the loop I append 2 rows of blanks and 1 row of colons, then at the end I chop off that divider row and append the pool border before performing the replaces.

**EDIT**: Saved 3 bytes by switching `@` to the most-often used variable, and swapping initialization order.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>124</s> <s>120</s> 117 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Hyper Neutrino</sup>

```python
l,x=input()
o='+--%s--+\n| +%s+ |\n'%(('-'*l,)*2)
print o+'| |%s| |\n'*(x*3-1)%((' '*l,' '*l,':'*l)*x)[:-1]+o[-2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsMgEEDRfU4xGxnHcaCx7UbISZLuGwgq1YIB725r6ebzFy@d5RmD6/2wddlDehdNU1yQRVQW4S00YJUZ2hZQaY2C5rBkHE3ptYcCkbFBU7n9hNHVXGWmIWHIf/23ZCqtXuYHx1WcH9f7/WJvHw)

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsIwEEDRfU@RTZjMTAa0VZRAT9J2byEkwUSIkLvHKm7e4vPTuzxiGHv3ts57SK9icIgzsIjOIryGplhnVm0NoI0BAfIWacQhPfdQVOQjNtV0br@HJm1Afae/7hCRKi5uokrG8w3Fy33juDgn563368lePg) (your variable `t` is unnecessary)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>128</s> 126 bytes

```python
L,x=input()
k='+'+'-'*(L+4)+'+\n| +'+'-'*L+'+ |\n'
f=lambda k:'| |'+k*L+'| |\n'
print k+f(':').join([f(' ')*2]*x)[:-1]+k[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlNCoMwFIT3nuLtXn5UVNpNIDfIDaILS5GmaZ9BUrCQu8dIyyy@mfnCNz5WGnI29a4dhU9kvPIaZUmDghl54aWPlOB/mUJII2G16Nf8vt1n8AoTJJT@lOknw@YogpcLQ4W8fa6OmC0DkIthEju3qukn6a06mXPfdfX1AA)

-2 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYlNCoMwFIT3nuLtXn5UVNpNIDfIDaILS5GmaZ9BUrCQu8dIyyy@mfnCNz5WGnI29a4dhU9kvPIaZUmDghl54aWPlOB/mUJII2G16Nf8vt1n8AoTJJT@lOknw@YogpcLQ4W8fa6OmC0DkIthEju3qukn6a06mXPfdfX1AA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Right, thanks, I don't know what I was thinking with those extra brackets :P

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>52</s> 51 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
:┌* +1Ο;@*┐1ΟG∙⁴++⁰
b3*Ie4+⁰b3*He⁰32žbH∫3*2+4;e :*ž
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=YjMqSGUlM0EldTI1MEMqJTIwKzEldTAzOUYlM0JAKiV1MjUxMDEldTAzOUZHJXUyMjE5JXUyMDc0KytiMypJZTQrJTNBJXUyNTBDKiUyMCsxJXUwMzlGJTNCQColdTI1MTAxJXUwMzlGRyV1MjIxOSV1MjA3NCsrJXUyMjA2MCV1MjU2QzViSCV1MjIyQjMqMis0JTNCZSUyMCUzQSoldTAxN0U_,inputs=NSUwQTUw)
Not bad considering that 20 bytes of this is a rectangle function, which charcoal has a built-in for.

Explanation:

```
Rectangle function: (example: on stack 4, 2)
:                   duplicate the top of stack (X pos)      [4, 2, 2]
 ┌*                 get that many "-"es                     [4, 2, "--"]
    +               push "+"                                [4, 2, "--", "+"]
     1Ο             wrap the dashes in pluses               [4, 2, "+--+"]
       ;            get the duplicated X position           [4, "+--+", 2]
        @*          get that many spaces                    [4, "+--+", "  "]
          ┐         push "|"                                [4, "+--+", "  ", "|"]
           1Ο       wrap the spaces with "|"                [4, "+--+", "|  |"]
             G      get the Y value ontop                   ["+--+", "|  |", 4]
              ∙     get an array with that many strings     ["+--+", ["|  |", "|  |", "|  |", "|  |"]]
               ⁴    duplicate the dashes wrapped in pluses  ["+--+", ["|  |", "|  |", "|  |", "|  |"], "+--+"]
                ++  add everything to one array             [["+--+", "|  |", "|  |", "|  |", "|  |", "+--+"]]
Main function: (example input: 2, 5)
b3*                              push variable B (input 1, Y length) multiplied by 3                     [6]
   I                             increase it                                                             [7]
    e4+                          push variable E (input 2, X length) + 4                                 [7, 9]
       ⁰                         execute the rectangle function [in X: E+4, Y: b*3+1]                    [["+---------+","|         |","|         |","|         |","|         |","|         |","|         |","|         |","+---------+"]]
        b3*                      push variable B * 3                                                     [["+---------+",..,"+---------+"], 6]
           H                     decrease it                                                             [["+---------+",..,"+---------+"], 5]
            e                    push variable E                                                         [["+---------+",..,"+---------+"], 5, 5]
             ⁰                   execute the rectangle function [on X: E, Y: B*3-1]                      [["+---------+",..,"+---------+"], ["+-----+","|     |","|     |","|     |","|     |","|     |","+-----+"]]
              32ž                at coordinates [3;2] (1-indexed) in the first rectangle put in the 2nd  [["+---------+",
                                                                                                           "| +-----+ |",
                                                                                                           "| |     | |",
                                                                                                           "| |     | |",
                                                                                                           "| |     | |",
                                                                                                           "| |     | |",
                                                                                                           "| |     | |",
                                                                                                           "| +-----+ |",
                                                                                                           "+---------+"]
                 bH∫             iterate over the numbers from 1 to B-1:                                 [[...], 1]
                    3*2+           push pop()*3+2                                                        [[...], 5]
                        4;         push 4 one below the stack                                            [[...], 4, 5]
                          e        push the variable E (X length)                                        [[...], 4, 5, 5]
                            :*     get that many colons                                                  [[...], 4, 5, ":::::"]
                              ž    insert [at coordinates [4; cIter*3+2] the colons]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 202 bytes

```cs
(L,x)=>{char p='+',n='\n',e=' ';string v="|",r="",s=p+new string('-',L+4)+p+n,q=v+e+p+new string('-',L)+p+e+v+n;r+=s+q;for(int i=0;i<3*x-1;)r+=v+e+v+new string(i++%3<2?e:':',L)+v+e+v+n;r+=q+s;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9BS8NAEIXv/RVDQDbrbEpqLUI3Ww@CpwiCh168hLipC@1us7tdKzW/PSapGEEPvsMwzPvmMVO6pDRWttCp3BbOwaM1G1vsJv3kNNRezhdelRCMeoGHQumYflsj1Ovp3Xm5m94fdJkp7RkMxXmr9GYFFYhJG@fsSMXqVL4WFvaCIGFakGdNmBQECD/DEET0ETEroog5sUct375iYpIQluM1xW7KahFQ4m@/dyUG1NyicFjzyti4OwaUSLnK5pfHZMZp54UzNq4rxIt5dnUrl2Q5BIUxqEbHrfQHq8HypuWTv56/M9qZrZyurfIyV1rGVbxIGSwo5f/lbzp@lv5caIauaT8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 153 bytes

```php
for(;$i-2<$z=3*$argv[2]+1;$i++)echo str_pad(strrev($r=["--+","+ |","| |"][!($b=$i>1&$i<$z)?$i&&$i<$z+1?1:0:2]),$argv[1]+3,"- :"[$b?$i%3!=1?1:2:0])."$r
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBDoMgEEX3nkInUwNFGsEdSj0IIY22trKS0MZF490p1s2byc/L87OPXe9nn@EQXqs2wKGCpt4Bto3PJZAWHZcdfnVz/ktGWibSyBid7vOSvz/h5ocHSTdMK8GwVzhLCZZviVuiNQXBUaO7ihJditEeXXm8TPRC1UpaWh19YVlTAc8VGByTd2oKvTtS1ZZeAEMGbYw/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 97 bytes

```python
L,x=input()
for i in'01'+'223'*~-x+'2210':r=('+|||-   -+||'+L*'-- :')[int(i)::4];print r+r[2::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoQwDADAu6/ILa01YKsgZPEH/kC8LptLLaGCQtmvV73NpCv/9hhqXbpzlpiObGzz3RUEJGLv0WEIA7Z/Ol/5Hllng66UQgBAD9AtLRIBo10lZiOWedw@SZ@AOl0DM/mt1qkbbw)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 98 bytes

```python
L,x=input()
s='+---| +-%s+-+---'%'|:'.join(['| '*5]*x)
while s:print s[:3]+s[3]*L+s[2::-1];s=s[4:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZLCoMwEADQvafIRkYTR6gfClNyA28QZlkwpcTgRGohd0/r6r34TesWhlKW7rQ@xCM1bSUWDCJmZbAWg9ehhkzQvzYfGgdZgZ5Zn231Wf37qYTi7kNS4mhkI25kvfwZiPDGD7HiJuJS7t30Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＦη«Ｍ³↑Ｐ×θ:»←Ｂ⁺θ²⁺×³η¹↖←Ｂ⁺θ⁶⁺×³η³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nnXndoCI7e/3LDu3/dDq93vWHtr8qG3i@z0bDk8/t8Pq0O5HbRPe71n0qHHXuR2HNgGpw9MPbQaq3PmobRqS1KPGbQi5zf//mxpwmQIA)

This is a more Charcoal-y algorithm than my other answer.

Comment: Charcoal has officially taken over the whole challenge. 4/10 answers are in Charcoal...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Well, it's a language specifically designed to golf ascii-art, so that's what you get for it. ;)

Comment: Explanation request.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder And three of them are the same length too!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 195 bytes

```c
#define P printf
y;f(L,l){char s[L+1],t[L+1];memset(s,45,L);memset(t,58,L);t[L]=s[L]=0;P("+-%s-+\n|+%s+|\n",s,s);for(y=3*l;y-->1;y%3?P("||%*c||\n",L,32):P("||%s||\n",t));P("|+%s+|\n+-%s-+",s,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/LasMwEEX3/grhYNBjBLIdQ6lI@wNeZF9nERSpNcRKkNSCifLtrmw3y2YzjzuXMzOKfyo1TZuTNr3VaI@urrfBZKM0uIUzuamvo0P@o2XlAcKS5KAHrwP2sG2gJY82QPMyt8l02Pk5CLnHOeOF56yzkRWexc7m4METaS4Oj7uanuXI@Vspx6J@T@4YC6riYmuhrsjrqvlVCoTMyAdqRf8B71O6Gw3H3uKfS38i6JYhZHApAFVEpnp9DOedpZQm2iIaXAmon80bAc2zeVpQ/mtIqtPh21kkZHaffgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 124 + 1 (-a) = 125 bytes

```perl
say$o='+'.'-'x($l=pop@F),$t="----+
",$i="| $o+ |
",$e=($d="| |").$"x$l.$d,$/,$e;say$d.':'x$l."$d
$e
$e"for 2..$_;say$i,$o,$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HU1LCoMwFNx7ivAYiGLyakU3LYGuuusZihALgvQFdWHBszdNOsxmPsyEcZn7GNfhA3G61qyt3kvMLki43SuDzZFNqAsymBwdClKrI6vRlfDZOahi0I6Z4Q1OKbnmPc/6orNL8AXGRHrJolpmPP@FyUDSQYydapuvhG2S9xrto@fm3EQ7/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 72 bytes

```apl
{g' '∘,∘⌽∘⍉⍣4(g←{'+'@(⊂1 1)∘⌽∘⍉⍣4⊃(⍪∘⌽∘⍉)/'-|-|',⊂⍵})↑(¯1+3×⍵)⍺⍴⍺/'  :'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///vzpdXUH9UccMHSB@1LMXRPZ2PupdbKKR/qhtQrW6trqDxqOuJkMFQ010FY@6mjUe9a5CFtbUV9et0a1R1wFqedS7tVbzUdtEjUPrDbWND08H8jUf9e561LsFSOqrKyhYqdf@TwNa8qi3D2jUo941QKlD642BWh71TQ0OcgaSIR6ewf/BDgFygJS6@qPuFqD2NJDhXIYGCukKRlxGIMqYyxREmUIEDU0B)

A function that takes L on the left and x on the right.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 111 bytes

```hs
r=replicate
a?b=a++b++reverse a
l!x=unlines$map(?r l '-')["+--","| +"]?map("| |"?)(tail$concat$r x$r l<$>":  ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoJAEEDvfsU4LKhsQhBdwm1/oFvH6DDKQEvjJuMaHvz3zQ4PHjx4L5rfLJKzOuVJwkCJC/K9I2t7a5W/rDMDFVKubokSIs9mpKn2CgJVWzUPtG2LB9zA4tP/064b@qZOFMQMn7g/jcK6I5254gUAmzxSiOBgWtI96S2CgfOxPOUf)