# I done did made a spaceship maw!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

### Introduction:

Inspired by [this comment of *@MagicOctopusUrn*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129523/it-was-just-a-bug#comment326309_129549) on [*@Emigna*'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129549/52210) for my ["*It was just a bug*" challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129523/it-was-just-a-bug):

> `8F9ÝÀNð×ý}».∊` I done did made a spaceship maw! And I was all excited about suggesting a 12-byte edit. – [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn) Jul 17 '17 at 20:10

Which is a [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands) (legacy) program resulting in this:

```
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1234567890
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P8wNWFiMWX//zhGOcOdw4BOw7DDl8O9fcK7LuKIiv//)

### Challenge:

Input: A non-empty string

Output: From outwards going inwards, add one more space between each character every line, similar as done in the output above, equal to the `length - 1`. So for an input `1234567890` the output would actually be this instead:

```
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0 
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1234567890
```

Why? The length of `1234567890` is `10`. So we start by outputting 10 lines: the first line without spaces; second with one space delimiter; third with two; etc. And then (without have the middle line with `length - 1` spaces duplicated), we go back to the initial input while going down.

### Challenge rules:

- Input is guaranteed to be non-empty (a length `>= 1`). (For single char inputs we simply output that character.)
- Any amount of trailing/leading spaces/newlines are allowed, as long as the output itself (wherever on the screen) is correct. (Empty line(s) in between output lines also isn't allowed.)
- Input will only contain printable ASCII characters excluding whitespaces (code-point range `[33, 126]`)
- I/O is flexible. Input may be taken as STDIN, argument, or function parameter. May be a list/array/stream of characters instead of string. Output may also be a list/array/stream of characters instead of strings; may be printed to STDOUT; returned as newline-delimited string; etc.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Input: @
Output:
@

Input: test
Output:
test
t e s t
t  e  s  t
t   e   s   t
t  e  s  t
t e s t
test

Input: ?!
Output:
?!
? !
?!

Input: Spaceship
Output:
Spaceship
S p a c e s h i p
S  p  a  c  e  s  h  i  p
S   p   a   c   e   s   h   i   p
S    p    a    c    e    s    h    i    p
S     p     a     c     e     s     h     i     p
S      p      a      c      e      s      h      i      p
S       p       a       c       e       s       h       i       p
S        p        a        c        e        s        h        i        p
S       p       a       c       e       s       h       i       p
S      p      a      c      e      s      h      i      p
S     p     a     c     e     s     h     i     p
S    p    a    c    e    s    h    i    p
S   p   a   c   e   s   h   i   p
S  p  a  c  e  s  h  i  p
S p a c e s h i p
Spaceship

Input: 05AB1E
Output:
05AB1E
0 5 A B 1 E
0  5  A  B  1  E
0   5   A   B   1   E
0    5    A    B    1    E
0     5     A     B     1     E
0    5    A    B    1    E
0   5   A   B   1   E
0  5  A  B  1  E
0 5 A B 1 E
05AB1E

Input: )}/\
Output:
)}/\
) } / \
)  }  /  \
)   }   /   \
)  }  /  \
) } / \
)}/\
```

Comment: Can we return a list of lines?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sure.

Comment: *Gets all just jittery* !!!SPACESHIP!!!

Comment: I knew I recognized that output. I love that this idea is still going.

Comment: TFW you vaguely recognize a pattern in a question `ಠ_ಠ` then realize it's because you accidentally made it a year ago `ಠ⌣ಠ`.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks for the inspiration. ;D

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for keeping the goofy quote haha!

Comment: interesting... bugged output in a challenge inspired by bugged output

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters, outputs an array of strings.

```
£qYçÃê
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o3FZ58Pq&input=WyJTIiwicCIsImEiLCJjIiwiZSIsInMiLCJoIiwiaSIsInAiXQotUg==)

---

### Explanation

```
£          :Map each element at (0-based) index Y
 q         :  Join input with
  Yç       :   Space repeated Y times
    Ã      :End Map
     ê     :Palindromise
```

---

### Original, 8 bytes

I/O is a string. Uses the `-R` flag. Includes trailing spaces on each line.

```
¬£múYÄÃê
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rKNt+lnEw+o=&input=IlNwYWNlc2hpcCIKLVI=)

#### Explanation

```
             :Implicit input of string U
¬            :Split
 £           :Map each character at 0-based index Y
  m          :  Map original U
   ú         :    Right pad with spaces to length ...
    YÄ       :     Y+1
      Ã      :End map
       ê     :Palindromise
             :Implicitly join with newlines
```

Comment: `S.ç()` FTW once again :-)

Comment: Serious question: would it be feasible to search iteratively through all 1 to 6 bytes long solutions for a puzzle like this?

Comment: @filip No: there are more than 256**6=281474976710656 (at least naive) combinations. It's like guessing a password.

Comment: @KirillBulygin I guess you need some kind of heuristic to avoid useless paths. Maybe a genetic algorithm. Must research this.

Comment: @KirillBulygin, there are over 37 *trillion* (37,764,717,485,592) possible ways of combining the characters available in Japt into a string between 1 & 6 characters long. If you include all the other 1 byte characters which can be used in string literals or compressed strings, that number grows to over **276** trillion (276,024,445,697,280). So, no, writing a bot to generate all those then filter out the valid Japt programmes then find the one (if any exists) that works for the challenge at hand probably wouldn't be feasible. Besides where's the fun in letting a bot do your golfing for you?!

Comment: Oop, pinged the wrong person in that comment; it was meant for you @filip

Comment: @Shaggy: "where's the fun in letting a bot do your golfing for you?!" What if you made the bot really, really short?

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>105</s> <s>99</s> <s>85</s> <s>84</s> 79 bytes

-6 thanks to @Kevin Cruissen and @Giuseppe

-14 from changing to a regex based method

-1 thanks to @Giuseppe

-5 thanks to @digEmALl

```r
function(w,n=nchar(w)-1)write(trimws(Map(gsub,"",strrep(" ",n-abs(n:-n)),w)),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcYxCsMwDEDRvadoNUlgD1lLQ3uBHsIxduMhqpEUdHwnkOHzvoz6iqPunK39GT3wzHlNgk5xIpdmBU3a5orf1PGn@xIAgppI6Qh3CBzTosjPyETBzyYaFeEDdDt5vC@tqF2nPeWia@tA4wA)

Comment: You can golf 1 byte by removing the space at `in(r<-`.

Comment: you can also swap the `<-` to `=` in the statement Kevin mentions

Comment: and you only use `s` once so you can just use it as an argument in `write` directly; bringing you down to [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY7BCsIwEETv/YoYL7uQQnstVj35E@IhxI1dqNuSpPbzY2rxNMMwb5iQj4rey2gTy0tFZwVQsUR@krLKL@IST2KUn4JKFH8tN8mHhEkcVf5U538LViO9uMEGWBELAVymIPQOmk6MdG3dIt7DuXngGjgR0AgxhTiPnAqsNaJpjZibKWmgGbTShjcoe9BXjVWRw2XX7c3u4mwdxYFnjfkL)

Comment: should that be a `1` rather than a `""` in `write`? I'm digging your use of `Map`!

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks! `write` has a whole lot of parameters to misremember.

Comment: Awesome ! [79 bytes using math :)](https://tio.run/##JcYxCsMwDEDRvadoNUlgD1lLQ3uBHsIxduMhqpEUdHwnkOHzvoz6iqPunK39GT3wzHlNgk5xIpdmBU3a5orf1PGn@xIAgppI6Qh3CBzTosjPyETBzyYaFeEDdDt5vC@tqF2nPeWia@tA4wA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: I was convinced I could beat this with the `collapse` argument to `paste` but it just isn't happening...

Comment: A lookbehind `Map(gsub,"(?<=.)",strrep(" ",n-abs(n:-n)),w,F,T)` *nearly* works for 72 bytes. Unfortunately I don't know how to cat out a list in <7 bytes...

Comment: since IO is flexible you can probably just return a list of lines and do `trimws(Map(gsub,"",strrep(" ",n-abs(n:-n)),w))` for 70 bytes. See for instance the two `K` submissions.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 1 bytes thanks to *Adnan*

```
εINð×ý}û»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FZPv8MbDk8/vLf28O5Du///j1YyUNJRMgViRyB2AmJDIHZVigUA)

**Explanation**

```
ε            # apply to each in input
 I           # push the input
  Nð×        # push <index> spaces
     ý       # merge the input on the spaces
      }      # end loop
       û     # palendromize
        »    # join on newlines
```

Comment: You can drop the `S`. Input is flexible, so inputting as list is allowed.

Comment: Tried to find something shorter, but I've only been able to find this 10-byte alternative [`εINúíJ}».∊`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FZPv8O7Dq/1qj20W@9RR9f//9FKJUo6SqlAXAzEJUqxAA) and some 11-byters like [`āεIsjíJ}».∊`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOO5rZ7FWYfXetUe2q33qKPr//9opRIlHaVUIC4G4hKlWAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Oh yeah, this is 10 bytes as well with input as a list of chars. Was in too much of a hurry for my train that I didn't really read the fine print :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Your first version is 9 bytes in legacy though, as `»` can be omitted.

Comment: Ah, good point. Hmm, will post it as a separate answer in that case, unless you want to add both to your answer? Either is fine by me.

Comment: Yours actually works in the legacy in 9 bytes as well if you remove `»` and change the loop `v` to a map `ε`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: I'd say yours is sufficiently different to post separately. And if you do yours in legacy we can aim for the shortest in each :)

Comment: [Posted the answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171728/52210). And currently Japt is beating us with 6 bytes I'm afraid. Or did you mean shortest in 05AB1E (Elixir rewrite) and 05AB1E (Python legacy)? :)

Comment: Does `εINð×ý}û»` also work?

Comment: @Adnan: Doh! How did I not think of `û`. I've used it plenty of times, while I've never used `.∊` before. Thanks :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yes, that's what I meant. I very much doubt there is anything we can do to beat Japt here ;)

Comment: `gÝûvyúJ,` I done did made a fancier spaceship maw! And I was all excited about suggesting a 7-byte edit. (Sorry, it had to come full circle)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen</sup>
<sup>-3 bytes thanks to ovs</sup>

```python
w=input();c=s=-1
while c:print(' '*~c).join(w);s*=w[:c]>'';c+=s|1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe6/wtmoU2FHZPhKdFkEjVHJDgujrNlMeDjktvTeMqdwslSOsOJmhhXh6QbZcMbEEAfojNR85JtmUqxrbZmlfARyNWF/TO7CvDD8)

Comment: `c==len(w)-1` can be golfed by 1 byte with `c+2>len(w)`. EDIT: In your new 70-byte version, `0<c` can be `c`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```javascript
f=(s,p=i='',o=s.join(p)+`
`)=>s[++i]?o+f(s,p+' ')+o:o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcqxCsIwEADQvV@hXZJwNejgIpxVwS9wLIWGmGhKyQUv@PuR7mZ@bzZfw/YTUt5FerpSPEruEgYUoiNkPVOIMimYmknhmQeAMPYEfl0gNkIBnahYikyL0wu9pJeD1rq9tKNSzR/IjnPN@m1NHslYx@@QamF/vN4O91XLDw)

Comment: [tried it with a string](https://tio.run/##FYzNSsNAGEX38xSlm2SYOg8gjC6k4Ka4cFkKLbWRlJIJjriuYDeiLYoUW43BRUn6kwZFqi6sL3C/Z4rj8lzOPd3WRcu0z/zwfCfQJ52i8JRrKqHyleNUtDKyq/3ADblosiZXe6YuhN/Y18L7t4RTcrjQu7pgrK0Do3sd2dOnrufWpZTlQ0rpGj8YYIshXvGFBfIqtvREC7pCH5dI6BErzEuU2HmFBBukeMM3MuQHlGFEM1pTjE9M8I6IxkcWR1jbUkS3NZu/x9TW5vY8pWfrjKu4s3hDET4QI6YJXo4pxy8ekFIfMxpgSUNk5QbnjBV/) from the answer to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and the output looks interesting

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｅθ⪫θ× κ‖Ｏ↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUCjUEfBKz8zD0SHZOamFmsoKSjpKGRrAoE1V1BqWk5qcol/WWpRDlCtlUt@eZ6m9f//hkbGJqZm5haWBv91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｅθ          Map over characters of input string
  ⪫θ        Join characters of input string using
    ×       a literal space repeated 
      κ     current index number of times
            Implicitly print each result on its own line
       ‖Ｏ↓  Reflect vertically with overlap
```

Comment: Charcoal doesn't reflect things like `[` to `]`-- or is that another separate command?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn There are separate commands if you want to transform the reflection. See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127164 for example.

Comment: I thought I had seen it reflect before, but wasn't sure. Neat!

Answer (score 6):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
┐² ×＊］──
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTEwJUIyJTIwJUQ3JXVGRjBBJXVGRjNEJXUyNTAwJXUyNTAw,i=U3BhY2VzaGlw,v=6)

The [7 byte](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTEwJUIyJTIwJUQ3JXVGRjBBJXVGRjNEJXUyNTAw,i=JTIwQUJDJTVD,v=6) version was too good for this challenge..

Comment: I like your 7 byte version. Would you be willing to explain how it works? Which operator overlaps the two `/`s into a `X`?

Comment: @Kaya it's the last character - `─` - vertical palindromize. The palindromization of Canvas [does cool things](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTND,i=JTYwJTYwJTYwJTBBJTIwX18lMEEvJTIwJTIwJTVDLyUwQSU3QyUyMC8lMjBkJTBBJTdDL2FiYyUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MA__,v=6). The overlapping part [has it's own character](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjRF,i=JTYwJTYwJTYwJTBBJTdDJTIwJTdDJTIwZm9yZWdyb3VuZCUwQSU3QyUyMCU3QyUwQSU3QyUyMCU3QyUwQSU1QyUwQSUyMCU1QyUwQSUyMCUyMCU1QyUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MCUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MCUwQS0tLSUwQSUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMGJhY2tncm91bmQlMEEtLS0lMEElMjAlMjAvJTBBJTIwLyUwQS8lMEElNjAlNjAlNjA_,v=6) too.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>54</s> 49 bytes

```ruby
->a{(-(z=a.size-1)..z).map{|i|a*(?\s*(z-i.abs))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xWkNXo8o2Ua84sypV11BTT69KUy83saC6JrMmUUvDPqZYS6NKN1MvMalYU7O29n9BaUmxQlq0kqGRsYmpmbmFpYGSXnJGYlFxLBdMKrggMTm1OCOzAEPGXhEm9B8A)

Takes input as an array of characters, outputs array of strings.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εINúíJ}û»
```

Input as list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3FZPv8O7Dq/1qj28@9Du//@jlTSVdJRqgVgfiGNilGIB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/u5nl4QqjO/3NbI/wO7zq81qv28O5Du//rHNqm8z9ayVBJR8kIiI2B2ASITYHYDIjNgdgCiC2B2EAplitayQFMlgD5qUBcDMQlYBF7IEsRzAoGsgqAOBGIk5HUZQBxJlgOpMoAaosjEDsBMcgFrmAZTSCrFoj1gTgmRikWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε     }    # Map each character in the input to:
 I         #  Take the input
  Nú       #  Prepend each with the 0-indexed amount of spaces
           #   i.e. ["t","e","s","t"] & 3 → ["   t","   e","   s","   t"]
    í      #  Reverse each item
           #   i.e. ["   t","   e","   s","   t"] → ["t   ","e   ","s   ","t   "]
     J     #  Join them together to a single string
           #   i.e. ["t   ","e   ","s   ","t   "] → "t   e   s   t   "
       û»  # Palindromize the list, and join by newlines
           #  i.e. ["test","t e s t ","t  e  s  t  ","t   e   s   t   "]
           #   → "test\nt e s t \nt  e  s  t  \nt   e   s   t   \nt  e  s  t  \nt e s t \ntest"
```

Comment: Oooooo, also this isn't valid because mirror changes the orientation of / to \ when mirrored, same with `[`, `]` and `(`, `)`. May want to add those cases to catch charcoal too. (Moved the other comments to Emigna's answer, because he was the answer I originally commented on)

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks for letting me know. Fixed it by using `û»` instead of `.∊`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```hs
(init<>reverse).(scanl(?)<*>tail)
a?_=do u<-a;u:[' '|' '<u]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxDoIwEADQna@4jdYEPkAPGHCUhMTFRA25QMHG0pL26uS3Wxne@l4U3sqYpNfNeYYzMZWds05PIEBgLUFm2QwVPJLQVjPWXn2UD0qWIoxkjWgkHmombWRGzVBNDiIWdIrHew75d4fxmVbSdk9W2roBtshX9hcLJewzIiyKW2dZWQ6JVeDfOBtaQipubd//AQ)

### Explanation

For a string (eg. `"abc"`) we apply first

```hs
scanl (?) <*> tail
```

which is the same as

```hs
\str -> scanl (?) str (tail str)
```

This repeatedly applies `(?)` (appends a space to each character in the range *[33..]*) to the `str` until there are that many strings as `str` has characters: `["abc","a b c ", "a  b  c  "]`

Now we only need to concatenate the result (minus the last element) with its reversed counter part:

```hs
init<>reverse
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*-1 byte from @Shaggy*

```
ÊÆ¬qXîÃê
```

---

```
ÊÆ¬qXîÃê        Full program, implicity input U
ÊÆ              Range from 0 to U length and map
  ¬             split U at ""
   qXîÃ         join U using " " times range current value
        ê       horizontal mirror
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DX4bZDawojDq873Hx41f//SsEFicmpxRmZBUoKukEA)

Comment: Dang; looks like you ninjaed me again! Lemme know if you'd like me to delete mine.

Comment: @Shaggy no, keep your answer, you are using array as input while I use a string so they are kind of different xD

Comment: `SpX` -> `Xî` for a 1 byte saving.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> 54 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to mazzy*

```powershell
0..($x=($a=$args).count-1)+$x..0|gu|%{$a-join(' '*$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPT0OlwlZDJdFWJbEovVhTLzm/NK9E11BTW6VCT8@gJr20RrVaJVE3Kz8zT0NdQV1LJV6z9v///@ol6v/VU4G4WB3EBgA)

Takes input via splatting, which on TIO manifests as separate command-line arguments for each character.

We first set `$a=$args` as the input argument. Then we set `$x` equal to the `.count` of that array `-1`. We then need to loop through the letters to construct the spaceship. That's done by constructing a range from `0` to `$x`, then `$x` back down to `0`, then using `Get-Unique` to pull out just the appropriate range.

Each iteration, we take our input arguments and `-join` them together with the corresponding number of spaces. Each of those strings is left on the pipeline, and an implicit `Write-Output` gives us newlines for free when the program completes.

Comment: Try this: `0..($x=($a=$args).count-1)+$x..0|gu|%{$a-join(' '*$_)}`

Comment: @mazzy What the ... how does `Get-Unique` work like that on the range? That's crazy! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 13 bytes

```
zZv"Gtz@he!1e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyqqTMm9pMohI1XRMPX/f3VDI2MTUzNzC0sDdQA)

Thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) for suggesting a 5 byte golf, which then inspired me to shave off 4 more bytes!

Explanation, with example input `'abc'`:

```
         # Implicit input, 'abc'
z        # find number of nonzero elements (length of string)
         # stack: [3]
Zv       # symmetric range
         # stack: [[1 2 3 2 1]]
"        # begin for loop, iterating over [1 2 3 2 1] as the loop indices
G        # push input
         # stack: ['abc']
tz       # dup and push length
         # stack: ['abc', 3]
@        # push loop index, i (for example, 2)
         # stack: ['abc', 3, 2]
h        # horizontally concatenate
         # stack: ['abc', [3, 2]]
e!       # reshape to matrix of 3 rows and i columns, padding with spaces, and transpose
         # stack: [['abc';'   ';'   ']]
1e       # reshape to matrix of 1 row, leaving last value on stack
         # stack: ['a  b  c  ']
         # implicit end of for loop
         # implicit end of program, display stack contents
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 5 bytes

```
ż∞v↲∩
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqIiwiIiwixbziiJ524oay4oipIiwiIiwiW1wiYVwiLFwiYlwiLFwiY1wiLFwiZFwiXSJd) -5 bytes thanks to lyxal.

```
ż     # range from 1 to length of input
 ∞    # Palindromised
  v↲  # For each character of the input, pad left by each of the above
    ∩ # Transpose
      # (j flag formats list of lines as a string)
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqIiwiIiwi4bqPdkl2auKIniIsIiIsIlxcXFxcXFxcIl0=) for 6 bytes, almost 2 years later

Comment: @lyxal Found a 5

Comment: Ooh clever. Wouldn't have thought of using transpose

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 115 bytes

```java
s->{for(int l=s.length(),i=-l;++i<l;)System.out.printf(s.replaceAll(".","%-"+(i<0?l+i:l-i)+"s")+"%n",s.split(""));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU/LTsMwELz3KxZLlWySWC1QHk3TUhAHDpxyRBxMmrRbHMeKnUqoyreHPEojgVQuWLK9OzP2zG7FTnjb1UeFqc5yC9u654VFyc/9wS8sKVRkMVMNGUlhDLwIVLAfAOjiXWIExgpbX7sMV5DWHA1tjmr9@gYiXxvWSgEeM2WKNM5nHTuHJGjxynjzfZLlFJUFGRguY7W2G8pcDDzpOw7OpM/CT2PjlGeF5bp@bhNqeB5rKaJ4KSUlnLhk6BGH4my0kA5OpYfMIYbUx1AR13CjJVpKCGN@Wfmt9TGnjY01EBySApDxxeXV5Prm9m5E3G/svi8bfd8tzvo61HUis0HdQ6PJ8mH8dOjLzrmZt3NvvaddAnYM8HNcqSh5VrqolQScVs38E1qvXeSkpmcTLqIo1pb@@S/5B7YcNLusvgA)

- -2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: `l-Math.abs(i)` can be golfed to `i<0?l+i:l-i` for -2 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! :)

Comment: could it be `l-i<0?-i:i`?

Comment: @thecoder16 You would need parentheses: `l-(i<0?-i:i)` (12 bytes).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
jⱮLḶ⁶ẋƲŒḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//auKxrkzhuLbigbbhuovGssWS4biE/8OHKy/igqzFkuG5mP//U3BhY2VzaGlw)

Returns a list of lines; output prettified over TIO.

Comment: A somewhat different 9: `,€⁶$LÐ¡ŒḄ`. Other, more similar, 9's: `J’⁶ẋŒḄɓjⱮ` and `J’⁶ẋŒḄjⱮ@` (I was looking for shorter but no joy yet)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm pretty sure this is optimal, I don't think there's any shorter way to write `LḶ⁶ẋ` or `ŒḄ`. However, if you manage to find a save, do ping me. :-)

Comment: Thinking about it a bit my `,€⁶$LÐ¡ŒḄ` may not be valid since it has crazy nesting so might need a `Y` and be a full program.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yeah, of course it's not. `['I', 'f', [[' '], 't', 'h', [['i']], 's'], ' ', 'i', ['s', ' '], 'a', [[' ', 's', 't'], 'r', ['i', 'n', 'g'], ' '], 'w', ['e', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e'], ' ', 'd', 'o', ['o'], 'm', [[[[['e']]]]], [[[['d']]]], '!']` At least I've outgolfed 05AB1E...

Comment: I said I outgolfed 05AB1E, eh? Bah, not anymore. :/

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 12 bytes

Just my mandatory Pyth submission. I am quite proud of this so an explanation will likely come soon.

```
+P_=jRQ*L;_U
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BP_%3DjRQ%2aL%3B_U&input=%22E%3DMC%5E2%22&debug=0)

```
+P_=jRQ_.e*d
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2BP_%3DjRQ_.e%2ad&input=%22E%3DMC%5E2%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/'(1+a,1_|a:!#x)$\:+,x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfXcNQO1HHML4m0UpRuUJTJcZKW6fCSim4IDE5tTgjs0Dp/38A)

**Explanation:**

Port of my [K4 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171725/69200):

```
,/'(1+a,1_|a:!#x)$\:+,x: / the solution
                      x: / save input as x
                     ,   / enlist
                    +    / flip
                 $\:     / pad ($) right by each-left (\:)
   (            )        / do this together
              #x         / count length of input,           e.g. 3
             !           / range 0..length,                 e.g. 0 1 2
           a:            / save as a
          |              / reverse it,                      e.g. 2 1 0
        1_               / drop first,                      e.g. 1 0
      a,                 / join to a,                       e.g. 0 1 2 1 0
    1+                   / add 1,                           e.g. 1 2 3 2 1
,/'                      / flatten (,/) each (')
```

**Notes:**

- -1 byte thanks to ngn

Comment: `,:'` -> `+,`­­

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç·9ƒù▌╘Ä┘e
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80fa399f97ddd48ed965&i=%220123456789%22%0A%22%40%22%0A%22test%22%0A%22%3F%21%22%0A%22Spaceship%22%0A%2205AB1E%22&a=1&m=2)

Outputs with trailing whitespace on each line.

Explanation:

```
%R|pmx{]n(m Full program, unpacked, implicit input
%           Length of input
 R          1-based range
  |p        Palindromize
    m       Map:
     x{   m   Map over characters of input:
       ]        Character -> string
        n(      Right-pad to length given by outer map value
              Implicit flatten and output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Oracle SQL, 115 bytes

Not a golfing language but...

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'(.)',LPAD('\1',1+LENGTH(v)-ABS(LEVEL-LENGTH(v)))))FROM t CONNECT BY LEVEL<2*LENGTH(v)
```

Assuming that the value is in column `v` of table `t`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07659/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( v ) AS
  SELECT 'test' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(v,'(.)',LPAD('\1',1+LENGTH(v)-ABS(LEVEL-LENGTH(v)))))
FROM   t
CONNECT BY LEVEL<2*LENGTH(v)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07659/13/0)**:

(SQLFiddle prints the values right-aligned in the column for some reason... there are no leading spaces)

```
| TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(V,'(.)',LPAD('\1',1+LENGTH(V)-ABS(LEVEL-LENGTH(V))))) |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                      test |
|                                                                   t e s t |
|                                                                t  e  s  t |
|                                                             t   e   s   t |
|                                                                t  e  s  t |
|                                                                   t e s t |
|                                                                      test |
```

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle results seems to only have single spaces in between characters? [See this screenshot](https://s15.postimg.cc/p2c6ipvmj/sql_fiddle_results.png). I assume this is due to SQL Fiddle and it works locally? Btw, not sure if SQL uses standard regex rules, but can `(.)` be golfed to `.` by using `\0` instead of `\1` like you could in Java for example? EDIT: Never mind, that is for `$0`, not `\0`.. ([Java example of what I meant](https://tinyurl.com/y839m3l9)).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Click on the down arrow next the the "Run SQL" button and change the output to "Plaintext Output" or "Markdown Output" and you will see the spaces.

Comment: Thanks. It indeed looks good in that case!

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.010 -nlF`, 34 bytes

```perl
$,=$"x($#F-abs),say@F for-$#F..$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZFqUJDRdlNNzGpWFOnOLHSwU0hLb9IFyikpwck/v934CpJLS7hslfkCi5ITE4tzsgs4DIwdXQydOXSrNWP4TIwNDI2MTUzt7A0@JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bl6OGwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>115</s>, <s>109</s>, <s>105</s>, <s>100</s>, <s>97</s>, <s>96</s>, <s>92</s>, <s>91</s>, <s>90</s>, 82 bytes

-5 & -3 thanks to [Kevin Cruissen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)
-8 thanks to [roblogic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15940/roblogic)

```bash
for((c=f=1;f;c-=2*(f>=${#1}),f+=c))
{ printf '%-'${f}'.c' `grep -o .<<<"$1"`
echo
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDsIgEADAO6/YVAyg0kSvgJ/wA8WVlV4KYb0R3o4z78h5zpbiB9hRaVpjoHB35NCGx0XTM8h@4mFudA1ojOhQ2378CNTZKtlpqBUVbN@WKtgCq/d@kbxsImEuYsz5qhET573@AQ)

---
Note that since the `\` is a shell escape char, the test case `)}/\` should be entered with an extra `\` like this: `)}/\\`.

Comment: Hi there. Is it possible to add a [TIO-link](https://tio.run/#bash) with test case(s)? Also, I don't know Bash very well, but is it possible to remove the spaces after `in` and `printf` like in Python?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, Thanks, see revised answer.  I'm new to *TIO-link* however, and am not sure how to use multiple test cases, since this `bash` code only inputs **a** string, (*i.e.* just one line).   The test cases all work however, though `)}/\ ` must be single quoted like this `<<< ')}/\' read s; ...etc.`  .  The spaces after `in` and `printf` are needed.

Comment: Thanks. And a single test case for TIO is fine. It's mainly to verify if everything is working as expected, which indeed seems the case. +1 from me. :)

Comment: In your new version you can golf 5 more bytes [like this](https://tio.run/##DctBDoMgEADAO6/YKhWIwdQzbN@iRbb2AoblZnw7de7zWXlvrcR1A3YJ5dnzJSgXrQMSzo4e@HI0YjBGbFlremMyZhgC2lkc5ZcqgXpaJU@61BQULN8SD7AZJvDed5K7RcSw53un2FqNXP8). Spaces after `for` and `do` can be removed. `f=1` can be changed to `c=f=1`. And `f=f+c` can be `f+=c`.

Comment: Oh, one more small thing to golf. Wasn't sure if it's possible in Bash, but apparently it is (one more reason why a TIO-link is handy ;) ), is by changing `f!=0` to `f` in the for-loop. Just like in JavaScript and Python, `0` is falsey and every other positive/negative integer is apparently truthy in Bash.

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoMgEADAO68gSgNoMcGrbD/RD2g3bPFSCHojvH078zmuxEy5GoNA4Dfa0ME6GXqBaqPv9kkzoLVNlHr@bpL64bRq1PWCWu7fGot0WS4hhEH5YRcRUxadmd/lwHils/wB), using argument `$1` instead of `read s;`

Comment: @roblogic, Good idea -- the OP *did* say the input was flexible.  I was fixated on STDIN...

Answer (score 3):

## Zsh, <s>95</s> 77 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P8tWJVpF2VDXMNY6Lb9IIVNBo1pXJUtPTyWrVjM1OSNfTQ0kXKGgoVKtUWxlpWlYq1lQlJlXkqagqgvRqVKdqaxbG1usoFLxH6SjlitNwdDI2MTUzNzC0gDIUdes1Y@JUQeyDEwdnQxdgYzggsTk1OKMzAIguyS1uASkyl4RpMThPwA)  
<sub><s>[95 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fcq9DsIgGIXhvVfxWT8JDEUxcWkx/iRegaN1MA0EQmKbwtBIuHak25Nz3p83WVMWszvjVnSUOnlkjBApJQpC1GJDpccZLNAoOMeXa8Q7QUTHuUgsrt8CFCP1bcvKMs32GzTsGow2ecClU4MZU06Vhpqlfd/XRYfT7S4eBc/pMyhv7FQclA9rddmsyTX/AQ)</s></sub>

```bash
j=$[$#1-1];for i ({-$j..$j})echo&&for x (${(s::)1})printf %-$[$#1-${i#-}]s $x
```

Takes input from argument `$1`. Set `j` to `length-1`. Iterate `i` from `-j` to `j`. For each character `x` in the input string, print `x` and append a number of spaces equal to `length` minus the absolute value of `i`

Comment: More idiomatic padding of `$x` (same byte-count): `printf ${(r:$#1-${i#-}:)x}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>143</s> 135 bytes

```pascal
var s:string;i,j,l:word;begin read(s);l:=length(s);repeat i:=i+1;for j:=1to l do write(s[j],'':l-abs(l-i)-1);writeln until i=l*2-1 end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBDsIgEADAr@ytRYsJHiG8wqPxQMu23WYDZEH7fIweJ1NCXQLrtSy9f4JAtbUJpc3RdExszyzRzbhRAsEQx6ocW8@Ytrb/IFgwNCDr6WrcmgUO603LwBAznEINx/o8XtMwWNZhriNrUtoo9z9O8E6NGMjz5a4NYIq33h8lLFh3Kl8)

I will probably win only against Lenguage...

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>88</s> 89 bytes

```php
for(;++$i<2*$e=count($a=str_split($argn));)echo join(str_pad("",~-$e-abs($i-$e)),$a),"\n";
```

requires PHP 5 or later for `str_split`. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/115df30d29922cfe22c71b5920d73f2e4b0d5e18).

Comment: Your try-it-online link gives the wrong output I'm afraid. In your output all lines also have leading spaces, instead of only between characters (or optionally trailing). The first character should all be in the same column in the output.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Didn´t look at the output close enough. Fixed. (Though imo my previous output looked more like a rocket) ;-)

Comment: It kinda looked like the head of an arrow to me. :D But +1 now that it's fixed.

Comment: If you place an actual newline instead of the \n, you save a byte :)

Comment: @Martijn I actually did only count one byte for it ... forgot to replace it when I pasted the code here.

Comment: @Titus - I like the bitwise not `~` I always forget about that one (and the new line).  I may steal your loop, by the way.  But not for this puzzle, I did one with `144` but I wrapped it in a `function` that's not required?  B4 Someone told me i had to.  I used `chunk_split` and `str_repeat`

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 23 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/'(1+a,1_|a:!#x)$\:$x:
```

**Example:**

```
q)k),/'(1+a,1_|a:!#x)$\:$x:"Spaceship"
"Spaceship"
"S p a c e s h i p "
"S  p  a  c  e  s  h  i  p  "
"S   p   a   c   e   s   h   i   p   "
"S    p    a    c    e    s    h    i    p    "
"S     p     a     c     e     s     h     i     p     "
"S      p      a      c      e      s      h      i      p      "
"S       p       a       c       e       s       h       i       p       "
"S        p        a        c        e        s        h        i        p        "
"S       p       a       c       e       s       h       i       p       "
"S      p      a      c      e      s      h      i      p      "
"S     p     a     c     e     s     h     i     p     "
"S    p    a    c    e    s    h    i    p    "
"S   p   a   c   e   s   h   i   p   "
"S  p  a  c  e  s  h  i  p  "
"S p a c e s h i p "
"Spaceship"
```

**Explanation:**

Has trailing whitespace on each line.

```
,/'(1+a,1_|a:!#x)$\:$x: / the solution
                     x: / save input as x,                 e.g. "abc"
                    $   / string,                          e.g. (,"a";,"b";,"c")
                 $\:    / pad ($) right by each-left (\:)
   (            )       / do this together
              #x        / count length of input,           e.g. 3
             !          / range 0..length,                 e.g. 0 1 2
           a:           / save as a
          |             / reverse it,                      e.g. 2 1 0
        1_              / drop first,                      e.g. 1 0
      a,                / join to a,                       e.g. 0 1 2 1 0
    1+                  / add 1,                           e.g. 1 2 3 2 1
,/'                     / flatten each
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>131</s> <s>129</s> 111 bytes

```c
i;x;f(k,j)char*k,*j;{x=strlen(k)-1;for(i=0;i<x-~x;i+=puts(""))for(j=k;*j;)printf("%c%*s",*j++,i<x?i:2*x-i,"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dTsMwDIXv9xQlqFLSJlI72PgxZQxpT7BdclOFdHULoWqCFGkqr14M2nJjHR@fz7ZWR63nGSFAw3vZCd3WY9bLrINTqJwfP4zlvVAlNF8jx6oAfArqJwDm1fDtHWdMiL9RV/VAkBhGtL7hLNVp5hjtyXNJyAYfl1lQKCkP03z9bhq0Jjns9gceRHKKmEvU85tlMgh6iMrlCEwLSiSfNVpO@cU/yV6YOCtvnI/N5irK/VBr41ocolOstq/lLrbl8uZ2tb67fyjImuZf)

*-20 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

```c
#import<string.h>
i;x;f(k,j)char*k,*j;{x=strlen(k)-1;for(i=0;i<x-~x;i+=puts(""))for(j=k;*j;)printf("%c%*s",*j++,i<x?i:2*x-i,"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7LbsIwELznK1IjJDuxq4RCXybQVuIL4NhLZByySTFW7EqWUPrr6bZqfVnNzM7MrhInpaZpBmd7Gfza@QHM6bbdJCCDbGjPO6baesh6nnXyGio0fGhDeyZK2VwGClUhYR3EV5CQV/bTO0oIYz@rruolhpjFSt9QMlfzzBHsyXOOkS08L7IggKNfjtPsqBswOj3s9gcaWHqNMZeKzbshPDB8CMf/ETkm6EjPNRiK/uQ3SV4I@0NeOx/J9ibCva2Vdi3YqBSr17dyF2m5uFuu7h8enwqUxukb)

Or, if length can be accepted as a parameter:

### C (gcc), <s>105</s> 102 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat!*

```c
i;x;f(k,x,j)char*k,*j;{for(i=!x--;i<x-~x;i+=puts(""))for(j=k;*j;)printf("%c%*s",*j++,i<x?i:2*x-i,"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7NbsIwEITveQpjhGQndgW09M8EWiSeAI69RK5DNinGil3JEkpfPd1WrW8zs9@MVsuT1uMIKqqadSKKluum6vNO5K261peeQTmJUipYR/kVFRSl@wyeUcr5z7UtO4Ukdz3YUDM607PcUywXhcDKFp6XeZQgkFfDOIWzu/Rh7QPip5tmk03fTQ3WkOP@cGSRk2sa8kRu3iwVkeNnURDsfBiLDFf/H6ghQ5icK7AMq9nvCH2h/E8F40My20mSB1dp4xtwKZmvXneLfbKL5e3d6v7h8WmO0TB@Aw)

Comment: @ceilingcat huh!

Comment: In your 102 bytes long golf, I think the global `x` is shadowed and thus redundantly declared.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <strike>113</strike> <strike>105</strike> 98 bytes

```
s=>{for(int l=s.Length,i=-l;++i<l;)WriteLine(Join("",s.Select(c=>$"{c}".PadRight(i<0?l+i:l-i))));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRT8IwEMff9ynOhYQtjAVUFBkD0fhiMCFi4oPxoZayXVI73BWMWfbZsWMgm3oPbe5//7v8euXU5kkqtmtCFcH8i7R4D6xq5k9RfRwk0kwjP1RuE0WJFP8X5zo1YmBZq/WbNDKXjAhmVmaBib13wjUmakg77wiWEG4pHGXLJHVQaZAh@VOhIh17GLZl0GrhUAbuc4paGCzh3CeoHNv2yJ8LKbh2eDhq2BnPbX/GFo8YxdrBYWcsWziQbXRNBPm2ADBgxbVKccO0OPBsElzAAzNDS6SXV2BpRO7OW5IXsWEpaEGaIAQlPo3rWAOwu6dn572Ly/5Vx/aq@nU9LSbUlfFJPZ@vGBcU46oud3qTm@5dRcv3rynC7E4wHoNTQBKgKkndH0MVFWD/h/5xpw37yTQMIKPcdoOaeenQL@Vvu9kHlH/vNMOmB/2OW@nJrfLMt98)

Comment: Hi there. Currently your answer is a snippet instead of a function or full program. This can cheaply be fixed by adding `s=>{` before and `}` after to make it a lambda-function. In addition, one thing to golf is removing the brackets around the for-loop. [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/y6v9ojlt)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! Forgot to fix that before posting...

Answer (score 2):

## **[Scala](https://github.com/scala/scala)**, **82 bytes**

```
for(i<-(0 to a.size)union(-a.size to 0))println(a.map(_+" "*Math.abs(i)).mkString)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PY5NDoIwEIX3nGLS1YyGhjUREw/AyrgyxgxYtAotactCDGfHEozL7@X9@Zpbnm31VHWAkrWBTwJwUw10EZDd3edwcI7f52Nw2twvlMPJ6ADF39lYGwk5h9VCUOznxjrUuxQzCBZYej0qGoy2BtOVFj0j6mMitHFJdtzjdStAbEoOD8mVR00ku9evNVZaFH457IZWjYKSKZnmLw)

Scala has lot of shortcuts that are helping me here and that is quite readable! 
[**Try Scala**](https://github.com/scala/scala)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to PPCG! Although it's a nice answer, I'm afraid two things are slightly incorrect. The line with the most spaces should only be output once in the middle instead of twice. And currently you print from `0` to `length` amount of spaces, instead of `0` to `length-1` amount of spaces. I don't know Scala too well, but it seem you can fix both issues with +4 bytes (86 bytes in total) like this: [`for(i<-(0 to a.size-1)union(-a.size+2 to 0))println(a.map(_+" "*Math.abs(i)).mkString)`](https://tinyurl.com/y7w6dqad) Again welcome, and enjoy your stay! :)

Answer (score 2):

## 8086 machine code, <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```
00000000  bf 35 01 57 ba 01 00 52  be 82 00 b3 ff ac 59 51  |.5.W...R......YQ|
00000010  aa 3c 0d 74 07 b0 20 e2  f7 43 eb f1 b0 0a aa 59  |.<.t.. ..C.....Y|
00000020  00 d1 e3 08 38 cb d6 08  c2 51 eb dc c6 05 24 5a  |....8....Q....$Z|
00000030  b4 09 cd 21 c3                                    |...!.|
00000035
```

Assembled from:

```
org 0x100
use16
        mov di, buffer
        push di
        mov dx, 1
        push dx
nextl:  mov si, 0x82
        mov bl, -1
nextc:  lodsb
        pop cx
        push cx
stor:   stosb
        cmp al, 0x0d
        je cr
        mov al, ' '
        loop stor
        inc bx
        jmp nextc
cr:     mov al, 0x0a
        stosb
        pop cx
        add cl, dl
        jcxz done
        cmp bl, cl
        salc
        or dl, al
        push cx
        jmp nextl
done:   mov [di], byte '$'
        pop dx
        mov ah, 0x09
        int 0x21
        ret
buffer:
```

Test case:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi there. I guess there isn't any online compiled for 8086 machine code, but could you perhaps add a screenshot of the output for one of the test cases? Then I can check if everything is correct. :)

Comment: Done. Also shaved off one more byte :)

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot! Unfortunately there is one small mistake in the output. The middle line now has `length` amount of spaces and there are 9 lines in total, but the middle line should have `length-1` amount of spaces and there should be a total of 7 lines instead (for the 4-letter word 'test'`).. :( I hope it's not to expensive in terms of bytes to fix?

Comment: Ohh I see. That's fixed now, I even reduced it by one more byte.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
(""#)
a#s|l<-(:a)=<<s,w<-' ':a=l:[x|w<(' '<$s),x<-w#s++[l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYwxDoJAEEV7TzEZSIDAXoAMlYWNVtohMRNg1TjAxsFAwdldsbGz/O@9/BvroxXxFgo4@xgxSDYc6CJk4pyTgkiziUwEUc6F5OW8TBSvi0JNspnMFGiallJVvuN7v540wwYAOnaHC7jXeByf@x5CsICnVkf8yh9G/Nduh6Y1u0Es@ndtha/qTe3cBw)

```
a#s                         -- take a string of spaces 'a' and the input string 's'
 |l<-(:a)=<<s               -- let 'l' be the current line, i.e. the spaces in 'a'
                            -- appended to each char in 's'
  w<-' ':a                  -- let 'w' be 'a' with an additional space   
 =l                         -- return that 'l'
   :[   |w<(' '<$s)   ]     -- and, if 'w' is shorter than 's',
     x  ,x<-w#s++[l]        -- followed by a recursive call with 'w' 
                            -- and by another copy of 'l'

(""#)                       -- start with an empty 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>148</s> <s>146</s> <s>143</s> 141 Bytes

```
function s($s){for(;$i<strlen($s);++$i)f($i,$s);for(--$i;--$i>=0;)f($i,$s);}function f($i,$s){echo chunk_split($s,1,str_repeat(' ',$i))."
";}
```

You can test it like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$s = 1234567890;
function s($s){for(;$i<strlen($s);++$i)f($i,$s);for(--$i;--$i>=0;)f($i,$s);}function f($i,$s){echo chunk_split($s,1,str_repeat(' ',$i))."
";}
```

Output

```
1234567890
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0        
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0         
1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        0        
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       0       
1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      0      
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
1234567890
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5be0156965de8ca701cdd9cab68634fd4e1afb18)

Expanded version

```
 function s($s){
    //loop upwards 0-10
    for(;$i<strlen($s);++$i) f($i,$s);
     //decrement so it's odd, from 9 loop downwards to 0
    for(--$i;--$i>=0;)f($i,$s);
 }
 //2nd function to save space
 function f($i,$s){
     //chunk it, split 1 char, insert $i number of spaces
     echo chunk_split($s,1,str_repeat(' ',$i))."
";}
```

**Attempt 2,  92 bytes**

after seeing @Titus answer I reduced mine to this:

```
for(;++$i<2*$e=strlen($s=$argn);)echo chunk_split($s,1,str_repeat(' ',~-$e-abs($i-$e)))."
";
```

I was trying to think of a way to use 1 loop, instead of 2...  Believe it or not, I almost never use the `for` loop in "real" code.  It was the `~` bitwise Not, that I was missing...

It's sill a tiny bit longer at `92` so I don't feel so bad. But I will put it in as a second attempt anyway.

`$argn` is the input from the command line

> Run as pipe with -nR or try it online.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/904a8d370d5603fae4c725aed7ceb3899c652e0e)

Comment: It seems to me that your first version would be 4 bytes shorter if you used a named function `f` instead of assigning an anonymous one to `$f` - `function f(` saves 2 bytes over `$f=function(`, and you save another byte every time you call `f(...)` instead of `$f(...)`. Alternatively, you could capture the `$s`, saving 2 bytes - `($i)use($s)` is 4 bytes longer than `($i,$s)`, but you save 3 bytes for each call to `$f($i)` instead of `$f($s,$i)`; in languages with automatic capture, like JS, this is more often a viable saving, because you don't pay the penalty of the `use` statement.

Comment: I do appreciate the help, I'm pretty new to code golf and don't really do it that much, one does get bored on the regular SO pages, though.  I did think about using `use` but it feels longer, to do that sense `$i` is dynamic, it would have to be passed in by reference. So it has to be `use(&$i)` and the `$i` has to be defined before passing it by reference to `$f`.  Which means setting it in the parent function, or before any other.  For the function it could be `function s($s,$i)` and just know it has to be called with `s($s,0)`  but it seems ugly, and that is around `11 bytes, use(&$i),$i`

Comment: We could use `$s` though and change the `\n` to a real line return. That gets it to `143`  2 from the line ending and 1 from use

Comment: Yes, I hadn't even considered putting $i into the use, because $s felt the "natural" capture, but it's always worth calculating the net saving. However, you can still save 2 bytes by just declaring a named function `f` instead of a closure: `function s($s){for(;$i<strlen($s);++$i)f($i,$s);for(--$i;--$i>=0;)f($i,$s);}function f($i,$s){echo chunk_split($s,1,str_repeat(' ',$i))." ";}` Extra functions like this are allowed according to this meta post: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/what-are-our-rules-about-additional-code-accompanying-function-submissions

Comment: Updated, saved a couple

Comment: I think your code block misses three bytes in your post's second line.

Comment: That was just a display issue in the post because of the line return.  Using a physical line return instead of "\n", saves 2 bytes (because you don't need the \ or the n) but because SO needs 4 leading spaces for a code block, I omitted those 4 leading spaces from the second line.  So the line return on here actually is `\n\s\s\s\s` so it will display as part of the code block, but the actual code doesn't need the spaces.  In other words, it is 141 bytes including the `"};` that was outside of the code bock on the post.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 43 bytes

```perl6
{(0....comb-1...0)>>.&{join ' 'x$^a,.comb}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1rDQA8IkvNzk3QNgQwDTTs7PbXqrPzMPAV1BfUKlbhEHbBsbe3/NA0lByWQfHFipTUXkFeSWlyCImCviMINLkhMTi3OyCxAETUwdXQydEUWUtes1Y@JUYeJ/AcA)

Returns a list of lines.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
 {                                         }  # Anonymous code block
  (0....comb-1...0) # A list from
   0                  # 0
    ...               # to
       .comb-1        # the length of the input string -1
              ...     # back to
                 0    # 0
                   >>.&{                  }  # Map each number to
                        join        ,.comb   # Join the list of characters
                             ' 'x$^a         # With the number of spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>28</s></sup> 20 bytes

```apl
{↑x,1↓⌽x←∊¨↑¨∘⍵¨⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR28QKHcNHbZMf9eyteNQ24VFH16EVQEEg0THjUe9WIN27@VHnIiCz9n8aSEFv36Ou5ke9ax71bjm03hio9FHf1OAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NQd3QyNjE1MzcwtJAHQA)

-8 bytes from Adám.

### Explanation

```apl
{↑x,1↓⌽x←∊¨↑¨∘⍵¨⍳≢⍵} ⍵ → input.
                ⍳≢⍵  range 1..length(input)
           ↑¨∘⍵¨     pad each input character with i spaces
         ∊¨          flatten each row
       x←            save that as x
  x,1↓⌽              join it with its reverse
 ↑                   convert to matrix(join with newlines)
```

Comment: 20: `{↑x,1↓⌽x←∊¨↑¨∘⍵¨⍳≢⍵}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR28QKHcNHbZMf9eyteNQ24VFH16EVQEEg0THjUe9WIN27@VHnIiCz9n8aSEFv36Ou5ke9ax71bjm03hio9FHf1OAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NQd3QyNjE1MzcwtJAHQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Żıṣj;Ɱ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNSVCQiVDNCVCMSVFMSVCOSVBM2olM0IlRTIlQjElQUUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD1UaHVubm8yJmZsYWdzPU4=)

##### Explanation

```python
Żıṣj;Ɱ  # Implicit input
Ż       # Push [0..len(input))
 ı  ;   # Map over this list:
  ṣ     #  Push that many spaces
   j    #  Join input by this string
     Ɱ  # Then, palindromise
        # Join on newlines
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
s=input()
r=range(len(s))
for i in r+r[-2::-1]:print(' '*i).join(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCoAgEADQ3a9wUwuDHAW/ojEaJCwv4jxOG/p6ozc/elsu6HqvAZCepo3gwBHPpO@EuhojjsISJKDkkVfrvLfz5okBm1ZSDWCmq8Bfe1cLxT3VDKQ@)

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <s>135</s> <s>133</s> <s>129</s> 112 bytes

```c
#define L{for(k=0;s[k];)printf("%c%*s",s[k++],i,"");puts("");}
i;k;f(char*s){for(i=0;s[i];i++)L for(--i;~--i;)L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xCoMwFEXn@hUhRUiMgc59lPYD3DoWh5CY@hBjSGwXsb@eGsHlcjjDuVq@tU7pbDqLriPNYqfAhtsF4mtogfuAbraMlrqsIq03KURbY00pB/@ZI8uwFggDWKZ7FarI9wTuCWwBheANyUpKhF8e3qzpO6Eho0LHMnGyFKft5rHVdrhfD1LR2IOfXuku9uizWNMf)

-2 bytes from [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171679/i-done-did-made-a-spaceship-maw/171713?noredirect=1#comment414446_171713)

-4 bytes from [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171679/i-done-did-made-a-spaceship-maw/171713?noredirect=1#comment414654_171713)

-17 bytes from [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171679/i-done-did-made-a-spaceship-maw/171713?noredirect=1#comment415285_171713)

Ungolfed:

```c
int i, k;
int f(char *s){
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\x00'; i++) {
        for(k = 0; s[k] != '\x00'; k++) {
            printf("%c%*s", s[k], i, "");
            // print the character followed by the empty string padded with i spaces
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    for(i = i-2; i > -1; --i) {
        for(k = 0; s[k] != '\x00'; k++) {
            printf("%c%*s", s[k], i, "");
            // print the character followed by the empty string padded with i spaces
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can golf 2 bytes by changing `putchar(s[k]);for(j=0;` to `for(putchar(s[k]),j=0;` so the brackets around the outer for-loop can be removed.

Comment: [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYzLCsMgFETXzVeIJaB5QNe9hPYDsuuyuBCjzUViRNNuQr7dxkAWA4fDzKj2o1RK10EbdJr0xH@XyCjl3MyB2e4G8W0FcB/QLYbRUpVVpM0u61o02OxNKBAsGKZGGarI1zzEY4gCsO56cpi2hZx@S78ZBzJJdCwTJ2tx2Z@f@SnD436SjIM5@eWl0nFEn8WW/g "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 86 bytes

```
func[s][repeat n l: 2 *(length? s)- 1[foreach c s[prin pad c min n l - n + 1]print""]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYs7DsMgFAR7n2JFlY8sGedrN7lDUqJXIHgESw5BQM5PSJrVjEab2NY7W0Wdm6v7BKMyqcSRdUHAOmPEbrNyeBZ/Q972kMq9E2vjYZBVTEtA1LbJq1F7oG@7h6RfKkIQVQdROBfRNZDj4Xg6X67T8NdH1IazX6KoXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>87</s> 81 bytes

*-2 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```
import StdEnv,Text
$s#l=length s
=[concat[rpad{c}(l-abs i)' '\\c<-s]\\i<-[~l..l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy7CsIwFADQvV9x0UIrGPH9ALvpIDgIdWs63Ka1Rm6S0kRRRD/dKDie5QiqUHtlyitVoFBqL1VjWgepK7f61j9WdxeEtksJVbp2Z7BBkgmjBbqsbbB8ildMDAsLshdBxLlYM5tzLtcse9NgQHnuU4e/MIGLkRo6XHcgDiGLRuPJdDZfLFfDKO/5jzgR1taz3d5vHhqVFH8cCN3JtMqz4gs)

Comment: Hi there. I'm afraid the output is slightly incorrect. Currently all lines also have leading spaces before the first character. The first character should all be in the same column, and the spaces should only be in between the characters (with optionally trailing spaces).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen fixed. It was a typo `lpad -> rpad`

Comment: Hi. I only now notice one more mistake a lot of other answers had too at first. Your middle line has `length` amount of spaces instead of `length-1`. For the 4-letter word 'test' for example, there should be 7 output lines instead of 9. You can fix that, and save 2 bytes at the same time, by removing the `+1` it seems. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fixed, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 26 bytes

```
Bounce@{Join[_,Iota@_*sp]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@98pvzQvOdWh2is/My86XsczvyTRIV6ruCC29r9fampKcbRKQUFyeixXQFFmXklIanGJc2JxanF0TppagrYDSJNaTppDmoNzRmJRsY5CNJcCECg5KOlAGCVADTC2vSKMFVyQmJxanJFZABMwMHV0MnSF8QyNjE1MzcwtLA2UuGJj/wMA)

### Explanation

```
Bounce@{Join[_,Iota@_*sp]}

       {                 }    anonymous lambda. input: _ (character array)
        Join[_,         ]     join each character by (vectorizes)
               Iota@_           the indices of _ (0 ... #_)
                     *sp        repeat a space by each index
Bounce@                       bounce the results (append reverse, but middle only once)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainbash](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Brainbash), 142 bytes

```
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-<++++++++++>>*,+[~+~->,+]~[-*[.~>[-<<.>>>+<]>[<->+]<<~>]~>+<<<.>>]>--[->+<<+>]>[-<+>]<<+[-*[.~>[-<<.>>>+<]>[<->+]<<~>]~>-<<<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hUxJDoAwCPyPSF9A5hMeSQ/VmOjFGHvn63Vc4lVIYGCW8SjrNpa6tKbOtgwIh5p8BXS9eEgoesnh2nkKUGsJj9pNIdkskIOPm2AG865LiKnmIv5z6@tubdjLNNdl3U8)

In one block:

```
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-<++++++++++>>*,+[~+~->,+]~[-*[.~>[-<<.>>>+<]>[<->+]<<~>]~
>+<<<.>>]>--[->+<<+>]>[-<+>]<<+[-*[.~>[-<<.>>>+<]>[<->+]<<~>]~>-<<<.>>]
```

### Explanation

```
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-          constant for 32
<++++++++++             constant for 10
>>                      move to counter
*                       swap tapes while retaining pointer
,+[~+~->,+]             take input in tape while keeping track of how many characters
~                       move to counter on other tape
[                       repeat counter times:
    -                       update counter
    *                       swap tapes
    [                       for each character:
        .                       output it
        ~>[                     repeat secondary counter times:
            -                       update secondary counter
            <<.                     output a space
            >>>+<                   make a copy of the secondary counter
        ]
        >[<->+]                 restore secondary counter    
        <<~>                return to counter
    ]
    ~>+<<<.>>           update ternary counter and output a newline
]

>--                     fix offset

[->+<<+>]>[-<+>]<<+     various counter restoring

    [-*[.~>[-<
    <.>>>+<]>[
    <->+]<<~>]
    ~>-<<<.>>]          same as above but subtracting instead of adding
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, <s>215</s> 214 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @v CHAR(32),@p VARCHAR(999),@ INT,@j INT,@k INT
SELECT @v=v,@=LEN(v),@j=-@+1FROM t
r:SET @p=''SET @k=1c:SET @p+=SUBSTRING(@v,@k,1)+SPACE(@+~ABS(@j))SET @k+=1
IF @k!>@ GOTO c
PRINT @p
SET @j+=1IF @j<@ GOTO r
```

[Per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), input is taken from a pre-existing table **t** with varchar field **v**. Max size I've allowed is 32 characters, which tops out with the middle line being 32*31=992 characters long.

I've used a pure brute force nested-loop (using `GOTO` which is shorter than `WHILE`) with manual string construction, not very SQL-like at all. Still the best I could do (MS T-SQL has [no native support for REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql/), except using CLR assemblies and manually importing `System.Text.RegularExpressions`).

EDIT: Here's the output for input "test":

```
test
t e s t 
t  e  s  t  
t   e   s   t   
t  e  s  t  
t e s t 
test
```

And here's a partial screenshot of the output for input "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":

[image: Screenshot of output for 26-character input]

Comment: Hi there. Do you perhaps have a screenshot for one of the test cases (like 'test' for example) so I could verify everything is correct with the output?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Added two sample outputs.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work great. +1 from me. :)

Comment: Also, I barely know anything about T-SQL, but is it possible to golf `@-ABS(@j)-1` to `@+~ABS(@j)`? I saw that T-SQL has a binary-not `~`, but not sure if it works in the same way as Java/JavaScript/Python/etc. regarding [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/52210).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Actually, that does work! Down to 214 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, <s>14</s> 9 bytes

```
aJsXPZ,#a
```

Takes the input string as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0as4IiBKRznx////ujn/gwsSk1OLMzILAA)

*Note: the PZ operator is newer than this question.*

#### Explanation

WIth example input `abc`:

```
           a is 1st cmdline arg; s is space (implicit)
      ,#a  Range(length(a))
           [0; 1; 2]
    PZ     Palindromize (append the reverse, but without doubling the center item)
           [0; 1; 2; 1; 0]
  sX       Repeat space that many times (vectorized)
           [""; " "; "  "; " "; ""]
aJ         Join a on those strings (vectorized)
           ["abc"; "a b c"; "a  b  c"; "a b c"; "abc"]
           Print (implicit)
           Each list element is printed on its own line, due to -l flag
```

Answer (score 1):

Lua: 132 characters

```
a=io.read()s=' 'l=function(o,n,z)for j=o,n,z do c=''for _,i in ipairs(a)do 
c=c..i..s:rep(j)end print(c)end end l(0,#a,1)l(#a-1,0,-1)
```

Long form:

```
a=io.read() -- using the input as a table, lua's version of arrays (and 
-- using it like an array anyway) Not 100% sure this is how the input goes
space=' ' -- need to declare this it seems so we can repeat it a number of times 
later
l = function(initialNumSpaces,maxNumSpaces,increment) 
for j=initialNumSpaces, maxNumSpaces, increment do 
  collector=''
  for _,i in ipairs(a)do  -- loop through the inputted string char by char
     collector=collector..i..space:rep(j) -- concat the char and spaces
  end 
  print(collector) -- print the collector
end 
end
l(0,#a,1) -- call the first half of the spaceship
l(#a-1,0,-1) -- call the second half of the spaceship
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to PPCG! Would it be possible add a [TryItOnline-link](https://tio.run/##yylN/A8EAA) with test code for your Lua program/function? (PS: You can add a trailing `#` in front of your "_Lua: 132 characters_" to make it a title like most of the other answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>102</strike> <strike>100</strike> <strike>98</strike> 96 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,n=s.length,m=n+--n)=>[...Array(m)].map((_,i)=>[...s].join(` `.repeat(i<n?i:2*n-i))).join`
```

-2 by using [...]
-2 from @Kevin
-2 by tweak @Kevin

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcnBCgIhEADQe19Rp50pnUPHyKJv6BhLiutuLjqKStDXG0Tv@lbzNtUWn5vkNLneZwVVsKoUHC/tJaLig5SM6vIgolsp5gMRR4omAzyF/0cdaU2eQW81FZedaeDPfPWn456lR8Rf643uNnFNwVFIC8ww3LOxbtoNiP0L)

Comment: Hi there! I'm afraid it's slightly incorrect. With input 'test' for example you are outputting 9 lines instead of 7. The middle longest line should have `length-1` amount of spaces as delimiter, but currently your middle longest line has `length` amount of spaces as delimiter.

Comment: changed from J to JS

Comment: You can golf `n-Math.abs(i-n)` to `i-n<0?i:2*n-i` for -2 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Here's a 74 byte version of your solution, taking input as an array of characters and outputting an array of lines: https://tio.run/##HcxBDsIgEADAux/prpY9eDRS48EXeGwa2QCtNHQhtDHx4tfR@ICZmV@82hLypiQ5X0ddWXe96I9iil6m7dkS0bUUfoMcBAdaOAM82oC6Y5pTEDCGMrubOAhnuYTTcS8qIGK1SdYUPcU0wQj9L2ruma1vBvxLszNYvw

Comment: @Shaggy Nice! but taking and returning array feels incomplete solution to me

Comment: It's allowed by the challenge spec: "*I/O is flexible. Input may be taken as STDIN, argument, or function parameter. May be a list/array/stream of characters instead of string. Output may also be a list/array/stream of characters instead of strings; may be printed to STDOUT; returned as newline-delimited string; etc.*"

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>135</s> 133 bytes

```
listen to S
F takes X
cut S into L
join L with " "*X
say L

X's-1
while S at X+1
let X be+1
F taking X

while X
let X be-1
F taking X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)